# runtime error 424 Object Required when referencing worksheet whose name was entered on another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

This is the first part of my subroutine

```
Sub AddReceiptToBlankCell()

' On the members named sheet, find the row for the entered year + term + course

Dim EnrollSheet As Worksheet
Dim enteredyear As String
Dim term As String
Dim course As String

Set EnrollSheet = Worksheets("Enroll Course")
enteredyear = Worksheets("Enroll Course").Range("C3").Value
term = Worksheets("Enroll Course").Range("C4").Value
course = Worksheets("Enroll Course").Range("C6").Value

' find the row for the selected Year, Term and Course.

'With Worksheets("Bloggs, Joe")
With Worksheets("Enroll Course").Range("C5").Value

   LastRow1 = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

The name of the person is entered on the Enroll course sheet in cell C5.
When I run it, I get a runtime error 424 'Object Required' on the row

```
With Worksheets("Enroll Course").Range("C5").Value
```

But if I use this statement instead (using an actual name), I don't get any errors

```
With Worksheets("Bloggs, Joe")
```

I've tried using this instead, but get same error message

```
Dim MembersSheet As Worksheet    
Set MembersSheet = Worksheets("Enroll Course").Range("C5").Value
With MembersSheet
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your line:

```
With Worksheets("Enroll Course").Range("C5").Value
```

With:

```
With Worksheets(Worksheets("Enroll Course").Range("C5").Value)
```

As the value of `Worksheets("Enroll Course").Range("C5").Value` is a `String` (or numeric), and then you want to use that string inside the `Worksheet` object reference, like `With Worksheet("SheetName")`

Comment: That works. Knew it would be simple but just couldn't figure it out